# Update JS-Beautify Snippet formatter

Tags: bug, status-review, stack-snippets

Having a JavaScript snippet like:

```
async function foo() {
  await import('./module.js');
}
```

and then tidying via the <kbd>Tidy</kbd> button, you end up with:

```
async function foo() {
  await
  import ('./foo.js');
}
```

which does two things I wouldn't expect:

- breaking the `import` onto a new line, and
- placing a space between `import` and the opening bracket

Note that, in this usage, this is the [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) function-like, not the static `import` statement.

Comment: There's a tidy button in the Stack Snippet editor? That would've saved me a lot of pain while trying to format code.

Comment: @GalaxyCat It's... opinionated, and a little wonky sometimes, like in the post. But it's there!

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [A small problem when using "Tidy" to format JS in the "Code Sandbox" if the code uses "dynamic import"](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/374509/289905).

Comment: Is *"JS-Beautify"* the official name of the underlying tool? The one referred to in the answer uses "JS Beautifier" (though projects and companies are usually not good at spelling their ***own main*** product, even on the main page (three conflicting ones are often seen on the same page)). Or is it meant as a common noun?

Answer (score 14):

Stack Exchange is using an old version of [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) to beautify JS, HTML, and CSS. Dynamic import isn't the only thing the old version gets wrong. It also breaks code when the code contains any of the following:

- Numeric separators (fixed in new version):

  ```
  1_000_000
  ```

  turns into

  ```
  1 _000_000
  ```
- Private fields (fixed in new version):

  ```
  class X { #foo = 'bar'; }
  ```

  turns into

  ```
  class X {#
    foo = 'bar';
  }
  ```
- Logical assignment (fixed in new version):

  ```
  a ||= b;
  ```

  turns into

  ```
  a || = b;
  ```
- Nullish coalescing (fixed in new version):

  ```
  x ?? y
  ```

  turns into

  ```
  x ? ? y
  ```
- Optional chaining (fixed in new version):

  ```
  x?.y?.z
  ```

  turns into

  ```
  x ? .y ? .z
  ```

The new version of js-beautify also supports dynamic import:

```js
const code = `
await import('./module.js');   // GOOD

1_000_000                      // GOOD

class X { #foo = 'bar'; }      // GOOD

a ||= b;                       // GOOD

x ?? y                         // GOOD

x?.y?.z                        // GOOD
`;

console.log(js_beautify(code));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.14.6/beautify.min.js"></script>
```

Let's update js-beautify.

Comment: Looks very good to me.

Comment: This is _still_ a problem: I had to [undo an incorrectly spaced `?.` token](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66143393/revisions) just now.

Comment: Still does not work for optional chaining December 2021

Comment: I flagged [JavaScript code snippet Tidy function injects a separating space into the null coalesce operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355267/175002) for status-review but that was before I saw this.

Comment: Btw, `??=` is even more problematic, combining the misbehaviors of both `||=` and `??` - it actually becomes `? ? =`

Comment: Ah yes, 3 years and still the same issue. I love how the devs don't care

Answer (score 3):

v1.14 improved one of CertainPerformance's bad examples

```js
const code = `
await import('./module.js');   // GOOD

1_000_000                      // GOOD

class X { #foo = 'bar'; }      // GOOD

a ||= b;                       // BAD

x ?? y                         // GOOD

x?.y?.z                        // GOOD
`;

console.log(js_beautify(code));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.14.0/beautify.min.js"></script>
```