# Please update the library versions included as "Options" in Stack Snippets (code provided)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-snippets

Updating the list of libraries was last done in response to a [7-year-old request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333042/can-we-have-newer-versions-of-third-party-libraries-in-the-stack-snippets-tool). That one was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) after Shog9 updated all of the listed libraries to the most recent versions available on cdnjs as of 2018-11-16, but it's *way* past time to do it again.

It'd be great if this could be automated as Shog9 describes in his answer to the above linked earlier request, but even if it has to be someone manually adding libraries to the selectable options, it would be a *huge* benefit to the site if someone could get that done.

### Please add the following versions to the already existing Stack Snippet "Options" dropdown lists

In order to add these additional versions, it's necessary to add additional `<option>` elements to the existing `<select>` elements. The JavaScript code in the page uses the attributes of the selected `<option>` to determine the value for the `src` attribute in the `<script>` that's added to the snippet's HTML area.

In an attempt to make this change easy, HTML for the additional `<option>` elements are provided in each section below. Adding the additional `<option>` elements to the HTML should be all that's needed to add these additional versions. The intent is to provide something Stack Exchange developers can just copy and paste into the HTML for the snippet popup. If SE developers need it in a different format, then please tell us, so we can provide it for you.

#### jQuery

##### Add the jQuery versions:

3.7.1,
3.7.0,
3.6.4,
3.6.3,
3.6.2,
3.6.1,
3.6.0,
3.5.1,
3.5.0,
3.4.1,
3.4.0

#### Additional jQuery HTML `<option>` entries

```html
<option value="3.7.1:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.7.1</option>
<option value="3.7.0:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.7.0</option>
<option value="3.6.4:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.6.4</option>
<option value="3.6.3:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.6.3</option>
<option value="3.6.2:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.6.2</option>
<option value="3.6.1:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.6.1</option>
<option value="3.6.0:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.6.0</option>
<option value="3.5.1:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.5.1</option>
<option value="3.5.0:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.5.0</option>
<option value="3.4.1:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.4.1</option>
<option value="3.4.0:jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.4.0</option>
```

#### AngularJS

###### Add the AngularJS versions:

1.8.3, 1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.7.9, 1.7.8, 1.7.7, 1.7.6

###### Additional AngularJS HTML `<option>` entries

```html
<option value="1.8.3:angular.min.js">AngularJS 1.8.3</option>
<option value="1.8.2:angular.min.js">AngularJS 1.8.2</option>
<option value="1.8.1:angular.min.js">AngularJS 1.8.1</option>
<option value="1.8.0:angular.min.js">AngularJS 1.8.0</option>
<option value="1.7.9:angular.min.js">AngularJS 1.7.9</option>
<option value="1.7.8:angular.min.js">AngularJS 1.7.8</option>
<option value="1.7.7:angular.min.js">AngularJS 1.7.7</option>
<option value="1.7.6:angular.min.js">AngularJS 1.7.6</option>
```

#### d3

##### Add the d3 versions:

7.8.4, 7.8.3, 7.8.2, 7.8.1, 7.8.0, 7.7.0, 7.6.1, 7.6.0, 7.5.0, 7.4.5, 7.4.4, 7.4.3, 7.4.2, 7.4.1, 7.4.0, 7.3.0, 7.2.1, 7.2.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.0, 7.0.4, 7.0.3, 7.0.2, 7.0.1, 7.0.0, 6.7.0, 6.6.2, 6.6.1, 6.6.0, 6.5.0, 6.4.0, 6.3.1, 6.3.0, 6.2.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.0, 6.0.0, 5.16.0, 5.15.1, 5.15.0, 5.14.2, 5.14.1, 5.14.0, 5.13.1, 5.13.0, 5.12.0, 5.11.0, 5.10.1, 5.10.0, 5.9.7, 5.9.6, 5.9.5, 5.9.4, 5.9.3, 5.9.2, 5.9.1, 5.9.0, 5.8.2, 5.8.1, 5.8.0, 5.7.0

##### Additional d3 HTML `<option>` entries

```html
<option value="7.8.4:d3.min.js">d3 7.8.4</option>
<option value="7.8.3:d3.min.js">d3 7.8.3</option>
<option value="7.8.2:d3.min.js">d3 7.8.2</option>
<option value="7.8.1:d3.min.js">d3 7.8.1</option>
<option value="7.8.0:d3.min.js">d3 7.8.0</option>
<option value="7.7.0:d3.min.js">d3 7.7.0</option>
<option value="7.6.1:d3.min.js">d3 7.6.1</option>
<option value="7.6.0:d3.min.js">d3 7.6.0</option>
<option value="7.5.0:d3.min.js">d3 7.5.0</option>
<option value="7.4.5:d3.min.js">d3 7.4.5</option>
<option value="7.4.4:d3.min.js">d3 7.4.4</option>
<option value="7.4.3:d3.min.js">d3 7.4.3</option>
<option value="7.4.2:d3.min.js">d3 7.4.2</option>
<option value="7.4.1:d3.min.js">d3 7.4.1</option>
<option value="7.4.0:d3.min.js">d3 7.4.0</option>
<option value="7.3.0:d3.min.js">d3 7.3.0</option>
<option value="7.2.1:d3.min.js">d3 7.2.1</option>
<option value="7.2.0:d3.min.js">d3 7.2.0</option>
<option value="7.1.1:d3.min.js">d3 7.1.1</option>
<option value="7.1.0:d3.min.js">d3 7.1.0</option>
<option value="7.0.4:d3.min.js">d3 7.0.4</option>
<option value="7.0.3:d3.min.js">d3 7.0.3</option>
<option value="7.0.2:d3.min.js">d3 7.0.2</option>
<option value="7.0.1:d3.min.js">d3 7.0.1</option>
<option value="7.0.0:d3.min.js">d3 7.0.0</option>
<option value="6.7.0:d3.min.js">d3 6.7.0</option>
<option value="6.6.2:d3.min.js">d3 6.6.2</option>
<option value="6.6.1:d3.min.js">d3 6.6.1</option>
<option value="6.6.0:d3.min.js">d3 6.6.0</option>
<option value="6.5.0:d3.min.js">d3 6.5.0</option>
<option value="6.4.0:d3.min.js">d3 6.4.0</option>
<option value="6.3.1:d3.min.js">d3 6.3.1</option>
<option value="6.3.0:d3.min.js">d3 6.3.0</option>
<option value="6.2.0:d3.min.js">d3 6.2.0</option>
<option value="6.1.1:d3.min.js">d3 6.1.1</option>
<option value="6.1.0:d3.min.js">d3 6.1.0</option>
<option value="6.0.0:d3.min.js">d3 6.0.0</option>
<option value="5.16.0:d3.min.js">d3 5.16.0</option>
<option value="5.15.1:d3.min.js">d3 5.15.1</option>
<option value="5.15.0:d3.min.js">d3 5.15.0</option>
<option value="5.14.2:d3.min.js">d3 5.14.2</option>
<option value="5.14.1:d3.min.js">d3 5.14.1</option>
<option value="5.14.0:d3.min.js">d3 5.14.0</option>
<option value="5.13.1:d3.min.js">d3 5.13.1</option>
<option value="5.13.0:d3.min.js">d3 5.13.0</option>
<option value="5.12.0:d3.min.js">d3 5.12.0</option>
<option value="5.11.0:d3.min.js">d3 5.11.0</option>
<option value="5.10.1:d3.min.js">d3 5.10.1</option>
<option value="5.10.0:d3.min.js">d3 5.10.0</option>
<option value="5.9.7:d3.min.js">d3 5.9.7</option>
<option value="5.9.6:d3.min.js">d3 5.9.6</option>
<option value="5.9.5:d3.min.js">d3 5.9.5</option>
<option value="5.9.4:d3.min.js">d3 5.9.4</option>
<option value="5.9.3:d3.min.js">d3 5.9.3</option>
<option value="5.9.2:d3.min.js">d3 5.9.2</option>
<option value="5.9.1:d3.min.js">d3 5.9.1</option>
<option value="5.9.0:d3.min.js">d3 5.9.0</option>
<option value="5.8.2:d3.min.js">d3 5.8.2</option>
<option value="5.8.1:d3.min.js">d3 5.8.1</option>
<option value="5.8.0:d3.min.js">d3 5.8.0</option>
```

#### Knockout

##### Add the Knockout versions:

3.5.1, 3.5.0

##### Additional Knockout HTML `<option>` entries

```html
<option value="3.5.1:knockout-min.js">Knockout 3.5.1</option>
<option value="3.5.0:knockout-min.js">Knockout 3.5.0</option>
```

#### VueJS

##### Add the VueJS versions:

3.3.4, 3.3.3, 3.3.2, 3.3.1, 3.3.0, 3.2.47, 3.2.46, 3.2.45, 3.2.44, 3.2.43, 3.2.42, 3.2.41, 3.2.40, 3.2.39, 3.2.38, 3.2.37, 3.2.36, 3.2.35, 3.2.34, 3.2.33, 3.2.32, 3.2.31, 3.2.30, 3.2.29, 3.2.28, 3.2.27, 3.2.26, 3.2.25, 3.2.24, 3.2.23, 3.2.22, 3.2.21, 3.2.20, 3.2.19, 3.2.18, 3.2.17, 3.2.16, 3.2.15, 3.2.14, 3.2.13, 3.2.12, 3.2.11, 3.2.10, 3.2.9, 3.2.8, 3.2.7, 3.2.6, 3.2.5, 3.2.4, 3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.5, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.11, 3.0.10, 3.0.9, 3.0.8, 3.0.7, 3.0.6, 3.0.5, 3.0.4, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.7.14, 2.7.13, 2.7.12, 2.7.11, 2.7.10, 2.7.9, 2.7.8, 2.7.7, 2.7.6, 2.7.5, 2.7.4, 2.7.3, 2.7.2, 2.7.1, 2.7.0, 2.6.14, 2.6.13, 2.6.12, 2.6.11, 2.6.10, 2.6.9, 2.6.8, 2.6.7, 2.6.6, 2.6.5, 2.6.4, 2.6.3, 2.6.2, 2.6.1, 2.6.0, 2.5.22, 2.5.21, 2.5.20, 2.5.19, 2.5.18, 2.5.17, 2.5.16, 2.5.15, 2.5.14, 2.5.13, 2.5.12, 2.5.11, 2.5.10, 2.5.9, 2.5.8, 2.5.7

##### Additional VueJS HTML `<option>` entries

```html
<option value="2.5.17:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.17</option>
<option value="3.3.4:vue.js">VueJS 3.3.4</option>
<option value="3.3.3:vue.js">VueJS 3.3.3</option>
<option value="3.3.2:vue.js">VueJS 3.3.2</option>
<option value="3.3.1:vue.js">VueJS 3.3.1</option>
<option value="3.3.0:vue.js">VueJS 3.3.0</option>
<option value="3.2.47:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.47</option>
<option value="3.2.46:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.46</option>
<option value="3.2.45:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.45</option>
<option value="3.2.44:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.44</option>
<option value="3.2.43:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.43</option>
<option value="3.2.42:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.42</option>
<option value="3.2.41:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.41</option>
<option value="3.2.40:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.40</option>
<option value="3.2.39:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.39</option>
<option value="3.2.38:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.38</option>
<option value="3.2.37:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.37</option>
<option value="3.2.36:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.36</option>
<option value="3.2.35:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.35</option>
<option value="3.2.34:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.34</option>
<option value="3.2.33:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.33</option>
<option value="3.2.32:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.32</option>
<option value="3.2.31:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.31</option>
<option value="3.2.30:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.30</option>
<option value="3.2.29:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.29</option>
<option value="3.2.28:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.28</option>
<option value="3.2.27:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.27</option>
<option value="3.2.26:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.26</option>
<option value="3.2.25:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.25</option>
<option value="3.2.24:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.24</option>
<option value="3.2.23:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.23</option>
<option value="3.2.22:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.22</option>
<option value="3.2.21:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.21</option>
<option value="3.2.20:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.20</option>
<option value="3.2.19:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.19</option>
<option value="3.2.18:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.18</option>
<option value="3.2.17:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.17</option>
<option value="3.2.16:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.16</option>
<option value="3.2.15:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.15</option>
<option value="3.2.14:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.14</option>
<option value="3.2.13:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.13</option>
<option value="3.2.12:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.12</option>
<option value="3.2.11:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.11</option>
<option value="3.2.10:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.10</option>
<option value="3.2.9:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.9</option>
<option value="3.2.8:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.8</option>
<option value="3.2.7:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.7</option>
<option value="3.2.6:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.6</option>
<option value="3.2.5:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.5</option>
<option value="3.2.4:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.4</option>
<option value="3.2.3:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.3</option>
<option value="3.2.2:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.2</option>
<option value="3.2.1:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.1</option>
<option value="3.2.0:vue.js">VueJS 3.2.0</option>
<option value="3.1.5:vue.js">VueJS 3.1.5</option>
<option value="3.1.4:vue.js">VueJS 3.1.4</option>
<option value="3.1.3:vue.js">VueJS 3.1.3</option>
<option value="3.1.2:vue.js">VueJS 3.1.2</option>
<option value="3.1.1:vue.js">VueJS 3.1.1</option>
<option value="3.1.0:vue.js">VueJS 3.1.0</option>
<option value="3.0.11:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.11</option>
<option value="3.0.10:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.10</option>
<option value="3.0.9:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.9</option>
<option value="3.0.8:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.8</option>
<option value="3.0.7:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.7</option>
<option value="3.0.6:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.6</option>
<option value="3.0.5:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.5</option>
<option value="3.0.4:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.4</option>
<option value="3.0.3:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.3</option>
<option value="3.0.2:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.2</option>
<option value="3.0.1:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.1</option>
<option value="3.0.0:vue.js">VueJS 3.0.0</option>
<option value="2.7.14:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.14</option>
<option value="2.7.13:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.13</option>
<option value="2.7.12:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.12</option>
<option value="2.7.11:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.11</option>
<option value="2.7.10:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.10</option>
<option value="2.7.9:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.9</option>
<option value="2.7.8:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.8</option>
<option value="2.7.7:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.7</option>
<option value="2.7.6:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.6</option>
<option value="2.7.5:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.5</option>
<option value="2.7.4:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.4</option>
<option value="2.7.3:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.3</option>
<option value="2.7.2:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.2</option>
<option value="2.7.1:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.1</option>
<option value="2.7.0:vue.js">VueJS 2.7.0</option>
<option value="2.6.14:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.14</option>
<option value="2.6.13:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.13</option>
<option value="2.6.12:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.12</option>
<option value="2.6.11:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.11</option>
<option value="2.6.10:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.10</option>
<option value="2.6.9:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.9</option>
<option value="2.6.8:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.8</option>
<option value="2.6.7:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.7</option>
<option value="2.6.6:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.6</option>
<option value="2.6.5:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.5</option>
<option value="2.6.4:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.4</option>
<option value="2.6.3:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.3</option>
<option value="2.6.2:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.2</option>
<option value="2.6.1:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.1</option>
<option value="2.6.0:vue.js">VueJS 2.6.0</option>
<option value="2.5.22:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.22</option>
<option value="2.5.21:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.21</option>
<option value="2.5.20:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.20</option>
<option value="2.5.19:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.19</option>
<option value="2.5.18:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.18</option>
<option value="2.5.17:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.17</option>
<option value="2.5.16:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.16</option>
<option value="2.5.15:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.15</option>
<option value="2.5.14:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.14</option>
<option value="2.5.13:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.13</option>
<option value="2.5.12:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.12</option>
<option value="2.5.11:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.11</option>
<option value="2.5.10:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.10</option>
<option value="2.5.9:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.9</option>
<option value="2.5.8:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.8</option>
<option value="2.5.7:vue.js">VueJS 2.5.7</option>
```

#### ReactJS

##### Add the ReactJS versions:

18.2.0, 18.1.0, 18.0.0, 17.0.2, 17.0.1, 17.0.0, 16.14.0, 16.13.1, 16.13.0, 16.12.0, 16.11.0, 16.10.2, 16.10.1, 16.10.0, 16.9.0, 16.8.6, 16.8.5, 16.8.4, 16.8.3, 16.8.2, 16.8.1, 16.8.0, 16.7.0

##### Additional ReactJS HTML `<option>` entries

```html
<option value="16.6.3:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.6.3</option>
<option value="18.2.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 18.2.0</option>
<option value="18.1.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 18.1.0</option>
<option value="18.0.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 18.0.0</option>
<option value="17.0.2:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 17.0.2</option>
<option value="17.0.1:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 17.0.1</option>
<option value="17.0.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 17.0.0</option>
<option value="16.14.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.14.0</option>
<option value="16.13.1:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.13.1</option>
<option value="16.13.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.13.0</option>
<option value="16.12.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.12.0</option>
<option value="16.11.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.11.0</option>
<option value="16.10.2:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.10.2</option>
<option value="16.10.1:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.10.1</option>
<option value="16.10.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.10.0</option>
<option value="16.9.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.9.0</option>
<option value="16.8.6:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.8.6</option>
<option value="16.8.5:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.8.5</option>
<option value="16.8.4:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.8.4</option>
<option value="16.8.3:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.8.3</option>
<option value="16.8.2:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.8.2</option>
<option value="16.8.1:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.8.1</option>
<option value="16.8.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.8.0</option>
<option value="16.7.0:umd/react.production.min.js">ReactJS 16.7.0</option>
```

### Personal priorities

While, personally, my main concern is jQuery, please update the available versions of all of the listed libraries and frameworks to their most recent versions, at least as much as reasonably possible. However, according to answers and comments on the earlier question, some if those are harder to update.

For more than 5 years, the jQuery library in [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) has been stuck at version 3.3.1, which was released on January 19, 2018

I would like to see jQuery updated to *at least* the major versions of the library that are in-use today, including [3.7.0](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js).

### Additional Stack Snippet changes which might be quick and easy to do at the same time:

- [Update the version of Babel Standalone (and others) used by Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386096/update-the-version-of-babel-standalone-and-others-used-by-stack-snippets)
  This should be just changing

  ```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>
  ```

  to

  ```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/7.21.8/babel.min.js"></script>
  ```
- [Update JS-Beautify Snippet formatter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401901/update-js-beautify-snippet-formatter)
  How much effort this one is will depend on what prettifier code you're using and how you're including it (e.g., is a newer version available and supported).

---

In case you, like me, cannot wait, here is a bookmarklet

```
(() => { 
  const library = {"text": "jQuery 3.7.1", value:"3.7.1:jquery.min.js"};
  const sel = document.getElementById("snpte-jquery-select"); 
  const opt = new Option(library.text,library.value,1,1); 
  sel.insertBefore(opt, sel.querySelectorAll("option")[1]);
  sel.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
})()
```

Other select IDs to update the bookmarklet:

- snpte-angular-select
- snpte-d3-select
- snpte-knockout-select
- snpte-vue-select
- snpte-react-select

Comment: More recent dupe: [Update the version of Babel Standalone (and others) used by Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386096)

Comment: It's a shame that the *very* poor quality of the initial revision of this question has resulted in something that's actually quite important receiving such a substantially negative response form the community. Another time, please put more effort into the initial version of the question. You, effectively, have an infinite amount of time to create the first version. Unless it's a critical, time-sensitive issue, then it's quite beneficial to take a bit more time to post something that will be received well by the community.

Comment: I've removed the additional request for updaing the package used for the tidy function. While it would be quite helpful for that to be updated, a request to update that really should be a separate [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Makyen I apologise. I do not use meta a lot, and the [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333042/can-we-have-newer-versions-of-third-party-libraries-in-the-stack-snippets-tool) was even terser. Thank you for the updates. I was travelling but see now I could/should have scraped the CDN for versions

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes but not completed, only in review

Comment: Doubt SE has anyone who can replace Shog, hence doubt they can do it. :(

Comment: FWIW, I left bits of script in the source for this feature that will scrape CDNs and generate the necessary UI code / tables for this. Depending on how much has changed around it, this could be as simple as someone pasting a few lines into their browser console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have updated the snippet script versions for  jquery, angular, d3, vue, knockout, and react.  I included any newer versions beyond the ones requested.  I did not tackle Babel or the beautify features at this time.

Let us know if you encounter any issues with the updated snippet libraries.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, Beatify still splits the `??=` on this `test ??= "x"` in JavaScript