# Will the stack-snippets formatter support modern JavaScript syntax?

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Clicking "Tidy" breaks JavaScript code if it contains `?.`

Before formatting:

```js
const a = { b: 3 }
console.log(a?.b)
```

After formatting:

```js
const a = {
  b: 3
}
console.log(a ? .b)
```

Comment: Chained duplicate: *[Update JS-Beautify Snippet formatter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401901/update-js-beautify-snippet-formatter)*. MSE: *[Snippet Tidy breaks Optional Chaining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348290/snippet-tidy-breaks-optional-chaining)*